# Probability : problem with conditional expectation

Tags: probability

I'm working on this problem :

> Aramis has challenged Porthos to a duel. Porthos can choose either that they
>   will fight with swords or with pistols, and he does this by tossing a fair coin. Porthos will win a
>   swordfight with probability $0.4$. If they fight with pistols, they shoot at each other alternately
>   until one of them is hit, with Aramis shooting first; on each attempt, Porthos hits Aramis with
>   probability $0.6$, and Aramis hits Porthos with probability $0.4$.

I have to give an expression for the expected number of shots fired, if they fight with pistols. I know that this is equivalent to compute the expectation of the number of shots fired. So let $N$ denote the number of shots if they fight with pistols, and let $N_A,N_P$ denote
the numbers of shots when Aramis wins and when Porthos wins respectively, so 
$$E(N) =
E(N_A) + E(N_P)$$
where $E$ denote the expectation of a random variable.
I know, in general : 
$$E(g(X) \mid X \in A)=\frac{E\{g(X)I(X \in A)\}}{P(X \in A)}$$
But I don't know how to use this definition in this case ... The solution states that : 
$$E(N_A)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2n+1)\times (0.6\times 0.4)^n\times 0.4$$
Where does this come from ? 
Any help would be appreciated,

Comment: not in the solution...

Comment: My mistake.  I was confused by the verbal description.  I was thinking of $E(N_A)$ as the expected number of shots, given that Aramis wins.  $N_A$ should be defined as the number of shots in the duel if Aramis wins, and $0$ if Porthos wins, and $N_P$ should be defined analogously.  Then $E(N)=E(N_A)+E(N_P)$ is clear.  Anyway, you don't need conditional probability.  Just add up $E(N_A)$ and $E(N_P)$ as the solution says.

Comment: Notwithstanding my last comment, @drhab's solution is much better.

Comment: Hmm okay, but then what is the law that leads to the sum of two expectation here ?

Comment: We have $N=N_A+N_P$ so the result follows by linearity of expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative route (so not really an answer to your question, but too much for a comment).

---

Let $\mu_A$ denote the expectation of the number of shots under the condition that Aramis shoots first and let $\mu_P$ denote the expectation of the number of shots under the condition that Porthos shoots first.

Then to be found is $\mu_A$.

Further we have the following equalities:

- $\mu_A=0.4\times1+0.6\times(1+\mu_P)=1+0.6\mu_P$
- $\mu_P=0.6\times1+0.4\times(1+\mu_A)=1+0.4\mu_A$

The equalities enable you to find $\mu_A$ and $\mu_B$.

Answer (score 1):

Since Aramis shoots first, when he wins, an odd number of shots, say $2n+1$ are fired.  That means that $n$ times, Aramis misses and then Porthos misses, and finally, Aramis hits.  Aramis misses with probability $.6$ and Porthos with probability $.4$, so we have $n$ events of probability $.4\cdot.6$, followed by an event of probability $.4$.

Is is clear now?

Comment: Hmm, I still don't know how to use the definition of $E(g(X) \mid X \in A)$... We have $E(N)=E(N \mid A)P(A)+E(N\mid P)P(P)$ where $P$ correspond to "Portos win" and $A$ to "Aramis win". Using the definition, $E(N \mid A)=\frac{E\{N I(N \in A)\}}{P(N \in A)}$, so can we say $P(N \in A)=P(A)$ so that $E(N \mid A)\times P(A)=E(\{NI(N\in A)\})$. If yes, I still don't know how to get the solution with that ...